# Are the async/await keywords in python 3.5 inspired by async/await in C#?

Tags: c#, python, asynchronous, python-3.5

`async`/`await` (syntax and keywords) in python 3.5 is very similar to `async`/`await` in C#.

C# example:

```
async void asyncTask(){
    await asyncMethod()
}
```

Python example:

```
async def asyncTask():  
    await async_method()
```

**Question**: is the async/await in python 3.5 inspired by async/await in C#? If yes, why?

Answer (score 6):

In [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) (the proposal to add the `await` and `async` keywords) it was [mentioned](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#why-async-and-await-keywords) that C# uses them (besides others):

> ### Why "async" and "await" keywords
>
> async/await is not a new concept in programming languages:
>
> - **C# has it since long time ago [5];**
> - proposal to add async/await in ECMAScript 7 [2]; see also Traceur project [9];
> - Facebook's Hack/HHVM [6];
> - Google's Dart language [7];
> - Scala [8];
> - proposal to add async/await to C++ [10];
> - and many other less popular languages.
>
> **This is a huge benefit, as some users already have experience with async/await, and because it makes working with many languages in one project easier (Python with ECMAScript 7 for instance).**

(Emphasis mine)

So the keyword names were indeed inspired by C# (and other languages) and as for "why" that's also explained in the last paragraph.